# Inorder traversal confusion

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

Currently, my main code for binary search tree looks like this:

```
public void add(int value) {
    overallRoot = add(overallRoot, value);
}
private IntTreeNode add(IntTreeNode root, int value) {
    if(root == null){
        root = new IntTreeNode(value);
    } else if (value <= root.data){
        root.left = add(root.left, value);
    } else {
        root.right = add(root.right, value);
    }
    return root;
}
public void print() {
    printInorder(overallRoot);
    System.out.println();
}

private void printInorder(IntTreeNode root) {
    if(root != null) {
        printInorder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        printInorder(root.right);
    }
}
```

by inserting values of 42,9,18,55,7,108,4,70,203,15 in the following order,
I am able to print out a tree that looks like below with the help of print side way method.

```
          203
      108
          70
   55
42
      18
           15
    9 
       7
           4
```

now, when I call tree.print(), *which should print in inorder traversal*, it prints out 4,7,9,15,18,42,55,70,108,203
but when I do the inorder traversal by hand, I get 4,7,15,9,18,42,55,70,108,203

I'm pretty sure that doing the inorder traversal by hand yielded a correct values
but why did the program print out different values?

Comment: You print everything in the left node, followed by the data, followed by everything in the right node. If you have a properly constructed binary tree, this cannot do anything but print all the data values in ascending order. That is, you're doing it by hand incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I 15 is branched left side of 18 instead of it branching right side of 7;;;

Comment: Yes, it could only be branched to the right of `9` or the left of `18` otherwise the tree itself would be incorrect.

Comment: @jose Can you please whole class file? I guess the problem is in add method which add new nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You construct the tree wrong by hand. 15 should be placed to the left leaf of the 18, not the right leaf of the 15.

```
                    42  
           9               55
      7         18               108  
   4          15              70     203
```